# VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error", anyone know how to resolve?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

When I run following macro in Excel, I get this 1004 runtime error and can't understand why...
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QOg0.png)

I already made sure macros are enabled

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myTableRange As Range
    Dim myDateTimeRange As Range
    Dim myUpdatedRange As Range
    
    Set myTableRange = Range("E1:E1000")
    
    If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set myDateTimeRange = Range("AC" & Target.Row)
    Set myUpdatedRange = Range("AD" & Target.Row)
    
    If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then
        myDateTimeRange.Value = Now
    End If
    
    myUpdatedRange.Value = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: in what line does the error happen?

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoints and single step until you get the  error?  Often when you are staring at the offending statement the answer will be obvious.

Comment: `Now` is a `Date` object and I would expect you need to specify the string format so it can be used. Also, as an aside, `Target` may be more than one cell so a check like `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` should probably be included.

Comment: Should also use Application.EnableEvents = false when changing cell values, to prevent loops

Comment: @cyberponk error happens in myDateTimerange.Value = Now line

Comment: Thanks all! Issue resolved in meantime... The code was fine but issue was that target cells were locked and sheet was protected.